# Average case complexity of the above algo

Tags: algorithm

Simple linear search to find max min algo

```
maxmin(a,n,max,min)
{
   max=min=a[1];
   for i=2 to n do
   {
     if a[i]>max then
         max:=a[i]; 
     else if a[i]<min then 
         min:=a[i];
    }
}
```

1.Average case complexity of the above algo given that the first if conditions fails for n/2 elements

---

Ans given

n-(n/2)-1 (number of elements for which first if succeeds) + 2 * (n/2)  (number of elements for which first if fails)
= 3n/2 -1

Is it correct??But when failing , why r we multiplying by 2??

Answer (score 1):

This is O(n). An `if` statement and possible assignment are O(1), so they don't impact the big-O classification (though they certainly do affect runtime to some extent).

Another way to consider the problem is by realizing if you double N, the runtime will pretty much exactly double.

Comment: O(3n/2)-1 is O(n)-1 is O(n). O means performance on the order of/that scales as n. Multiplying n by a constant doesn't change the scaling characteristic. Subtracting a constant from O(n) also doesn't change the scaling characteristic (when N is very large, that -1 will be infintesimal).

Answer (score 0):

Linear search would be worst case, O(n), best case O(1)